# I cant understand why this loop freezes

Tags: c, arrays, loops, if-statement, multidimensional-array

Can someone please explain to me whats wrong with this code?? shouldnt my board be filled?  ( i have two functions above, one to generate a random number and the other to print the array)

Functions:

```
void map(char a[3][3]){

    int row, column;

    for(row=0;row<3;row++){

        for(column=0;column<3;column++){

            printf ("%c       ", a[row][column]);

        }
        printf("\n \n \n \n \n");
}
}
float getRand() {

    return ((rand() / (RAND_MAX+1.0))*9)+1;
}
```

Main:

```
srand( time(NULL) );
    int r,c,ui,cntr,cntr2,ran,g,x;
    char kb, aray[3][3]={{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'}};
    getRand();
    ran=getRand();

for(cntr2=0;cntr2<5;cntr2++){
                g=ran/3;
                x=ran%3;
                if(aray[g][x]=='.'){
                    aray[g][x]='O';
                    system("cls");
                    map(aray);
                }
                else{
                    cntr2--;
                }

        }
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?  What should it be doing that it's not?

Comment: can you provide the code for functions map() and getRand() ?

Comment: Use debugger now on ^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `getRand` returns a number between 0 and 9, once the loop has iterated once, there is an `O` in `array[g][x]`.

On the next iteration, `ran` has not changed, and so `g` and `x` are the same values as before. Now, `array[g][x]` contains an `O` and so the else statement executes, and undoes `cntr2++`, which will remain at value `1`, causing an endless loop.

Comment: yes but thsouldnt that only be in the case of finding a value that already existed?

Comment: Expanded the explanation a bit - hope that makes more sense?

Comment: Thank you very much for the great explanation!